# recaptcha.destroy() does not work in custom theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django, recaptcha

I'm using two recaptcha's in a page which has two forms for different users.

I'm using custom theme for creating captcha using AJAX API as:

```
function showRecaptcha(element) {
    Recaptcha.create(
        'publice_key',
        element, {
            theme: 'custom',
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
}
```

And i use it in two modes:

```
$("#to-teach").click(function() {
        $("#sign-up-welcome").hide();
        teachForm();
        showRecaptcha('teachcaptcha');
        return false;
    });
```

and another for

```
$("#to-student").click(function() {
            $("#sign-up-welcome").hide();
            studentForm();
            showRecaptcha('studentcaptcha');
            return false;
        });
```

the `teachForm()` is:

```
function teachForm() {
        Recaptcha.destroy('studentcaptcha');
        signup.show();
        signupTitle.text("Sign Up as a Teacher");
    }
```

and similar destroy event used as `Recaptcha.destroy('teachcaptcha');`

And html for **custom captcha** is:

```
<div id="teachcaptcha">
                <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
                <div class="captcha-input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" class="input-recaptcha" />
                    <a class="fontawesome-refresh" href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()"></a>
                    <a class="fontawesome-headphones recaptcha_only_if_image" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')"></a>
                    <a class="fontawesome-picture recaptcha_only_if_audio" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')"></a>
                    <a class="fontawesome-question" href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and similarly for the **studentcaptcha**

The issue is if i use a `white` theme instead of `custom` and don't put any custom *html* in `<div id="studentcaptcha" or "teachcaptcha">...</div>` the **destroy()** works best but it simply don't work when i use `custom` theme and put my own html on both `div`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why `Recaptcha.destroy()` won't destroy old captcha... It's because `destroy()` is designed for non-custom captcha themes.

In its defintion, it has:

`Recaptcha.widget&&("custom"!=Recaptcha.theme?Recaptcha.widget.innerHTML="":Recaptcha.widget.style.display="none",Recaptcha.widget=null)` so it won't remove captcha completely when `custom` theme is used.

Solution is to write custom destroy method which removes the captcha's html widget manually using `jQuery` (or `JavaScript`).